# How can I make this image responsive?

Tags: css

I am trying to include a logo for my site. It needs to be responsive. With the following CSS  the image is OK with width, but the top & bottom of the logo are not displayed. If the site was not responsive, I would just put `height: 100px;` underneath the `width`. How can I make all the logo display, including the top and bottom bits of it, but still make the logo responsive?

```
  .header-image .site-title > a {
        background:  url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;

        }
```

The  rest of the CSS which my be making the top & bottom parts of the logo to not be displayed, is below.

```
.title-area {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 360px;

}

.header-full-width .title-area {
    width: 100%;
}

.site-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.header-image .site-title > a {
    background:  url(images/logo.png) no-repeat left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

}

.site-description {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.site-description,
.site-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: auto; /*added by me */
}

.header-image .site-description,
.header-image .site-title {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

I suspect that it is something to do with a container?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do, could you please build a live example in jsfiddle or other?

Comment: you want a "responsive" site and you are using floats? background image is not going to magically expand the content box. ever. Fiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a fixed height for an element doesn't automatically make a site "not responsive," but you might consider using `min-height: 100px;` (or whatever the correct height is) to ensure that important elements of the logo won't be hidden. Depending on what exactly the desired behavior is, you could also (or instead) set a relative height (e.g. `height: 100%;`)

Another possible approach is to use either the `cover` or `contain` keyword value for [the background-size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: `min-height` seems to work. Is `min-height` a 'responsive way' of coding? Thank you for the support!

Comment: "responsive" isn't a carefully guarded tradition or a list of css rules that are and aren't allowed, it's just a way of describing websites that display well across varying devices. if you use it well, sure. if you use it poorly, no. (that said, min-height, max-height, and the related width rules are often used in responsive designs)