# How do i get my image to be responsive?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

Im trying to get my image responsive so that when its on a mobile device de image will scale down but i cant get it to work.

I have tried using height and width 100%.

Can anyone help me?

this is my website: www.promegaekonomi.se (its the bbig image thats under my meny)

Comment: Try setting just height **or** width, instead of setting both to 100%.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make this image responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828377/how-can-i-make-this-image-responsive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-width: 100%` should do the trick

if your image is applied with css (rather than in an `<img>` tag), you could try:

`background-size: cover` or `background-size: 100% auto`

Comment: This works! my image is cut in two so when i use this it looks weird but still right and responsive. How do i line them?

Comment: Depending on the method you choose, you may also want to set no-repeat on your background image if you don't want it to tile itself. Then, you should probably setup a media query and adjust the height of your #full-size-image-wrapper div to be something more like 215px (on smaller screens) rather than the 386px it is on your desktop version.

Comment: both images are set in css with no-repeat. But there is a white line i cant remove? When i set the sizes for smaller screens there is a white box under the image that changes all the time. When you rezize the window you will see what i mean

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.0 then you can add only `class="img-responsive"`

Something like this:

```
<img  class="img-responsive" src="img/sponsor/nescafe.png" alt="nescafe">
```

Otherwise:

```
<img  class="responsive-photo" src="img/sponsor/nescafe.png" alt="nescafe">
```

CSS:

```
.responsive-photo{
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry cant add comment, if it is an image you may also want to add `height:auto;`to`max-width:100%`

edit- looking at your site if its the background image you are referring to spanning full width you will can add `background-size:cover;` and change the height using media queries as your site scales.

Answer (score 0):

Using css:

```
    img{height:auto; width:100%;}
```

OR...

you can covert your image to SVG file and it will keep adapt its size automatically...